# Changing color of jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the color of the header of the jquery dialog box?
I want the "?" and the header of the second dialog box (when you press the "?") to be filled with a red background instead of the standard grey. I tried it with the class ".dialog-title-bar", but it won't work. Can you help me?
Thanks in advance! :)

```js
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '400',
   height: '200',
   dialogClass: 'hilfe_arbeitsauftrag',
   buttons: [
    {
     text: "close",
     click: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
    },
    
   ]
  });

 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });


 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag, #icons li" ).hover(
  function() {
   $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  },
  function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  }
 );

$(".hilfe_arbeitsauftrag").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<span id='iconhelp' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help'></span>");

$("#iconhelp").click(function( event ){
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });

$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '200',
   height: '100',
         });
```

```css
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag {
  padding:  15.5px 0px 23px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  
 }
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }


.dialog-title-bar{
 background-color: red;
 
 
}
#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe{
     padding:  10px 10px 10px 10px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; 
  
}
#iconhelp_arbeitsauftrag{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right:10px;
    
}
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
#icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>




<button id="dialog-arbeitsauftrag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
      Arbeitsauftrag
     </button>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag" title="Arbeitsauftrag">
     <p> 

     Blablabla.

     </p>
</div>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" class="dialog-title-bar" title="Hilfebox">
<font face="arial" size="2">
  Some more blablabla.
</font>
</div>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `#iconhelp{background-color:red}` and `.ui-dialog:nth-child(2) .ui-dialog-titlebar{background:red}`

Comment: But this changes both of the titlebars. I only want to change the second one. Is there a possibility to differentiate between both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add 2 special `dialogClass`, you have already added for the first dialog

```
$("#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: '200',
  height: '100',
  dialogClass: 'arbeitsauftrag_hilfe',
});
```

then

```
.hilfe_arbeitsauftrag #iconhelp {
  background-color: red;
}
.arbeitsauftrag_hilfe .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}
```

```js
$("#dialog_arbeitsauftrag").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: '400',
  height: '200',
  dialogClass: 'hilfe_arbeitsauftrag',
  buttons: [{
    text: "close",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }, ]
});


$("#dialog-arbeitsauftrag").click(function(event) {
  $("#dialog_arbeitsauftrag").dialog("open");
  event.preventDefault();
});

$("#dialog-arbeitsauftrag, #icons li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
  }
);

$(".hilfe_arbeitsauftrag").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").find('.ui-dialog-title').append("<span id='iconhelp' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help'></span>");

$("#iconhelp").click(function(event) {
  $("#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe").dialog("open");
  event.preventDefault();
});

$("#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: '200',
  height: '100',
  dialogClass: 'arbeitsauftrag_hilfe',
});
```

```css
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag {
  padding: 15.5px 0px 23px;
  !important text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.dialog-title-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  !important text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
#iconhelp_arbeitsauftrag {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
#icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
#icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
.hilfe_arbeitsauftrag #iconhelp {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
.arbeitsauftrag_hilfe .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<button id="dialog-arbeitsauftrag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
  Arbeitsauftrag
</button>
<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag" title="Arbeitsauftrag">
  <p>
    Blablabla.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" class="dialog-title-bar" title="Hilfebox">
  <font face="arial" size="2">Some more blablabla.</font>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Do you see any possibility in changing the place of the "?" button? It's very close to the "X", but margin does not have any effect on it. Same as the color tag for changing from black to white. It always stays black...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I encountered another problem. Is it possible to change the "?" icon to the same button style as the "X"? I tried it with the color tag below the margin tag, but it doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply overriding .ui-dialog-titlebar, add this to your CSS

```
.hilfe_arbeitsauftrag .ui-dialog-titlebar { background-color: red; background-image: none;}
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/bvro69rt/1/)

Comment: But this changes both of the titlebars. I only want to change the second one and/or the questionmark-button. Is there a possibility to differentiate between both of them?

Comment: Apply the style to the ID of the one you want to change, rather than the class for all popups. `#yourID{}`

Comment: change CSS to apply this override only to children of .hilfe_arbeitsauftrag (or another class you can use to choose which dialog should be red)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#alertmsg").dialog({ resizable: false,
                title: "eDurar Alert..!",
                height: "auto",
                width: "auto",
                modal: true,
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                dialogClass: 'no-close',
                of: window
            });
            $('.ui-widget-header').css({ 'background-color': '#e9171f' });
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css({ 'background-color': 'red' });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution. Just use the combined classes of the header div to make a very specific target, then specify a red background to it. The selector would look like:     `.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-draggable-handle`.

See below for the updated snippet.

```js
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '400',
   height: '200',
   dialogClass: 'hilfe_arbeitsauftrag',
   buttons: [
    {
     text: "close",
     click: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
    },
    
   ]
  });

 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });


 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag, #icons li" ).hover(
  function() {
   $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  },
  function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  }
 );

$(".hilfe_arbeitsauftrag").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<span id='iconhelp' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help'></span>");

$("#iconhelp").click(function( event ){
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });

$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '200',
   height: '100',
         });
```

```css
 .ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-draggable-handle {
background:red;
}

#dialog-arbeitsauftrag {
  padding:  15.5px 0px 23px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  
 }
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }


.dialog-title-bar{
 background-color: red;
 
 
}
#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe{
     padding:  10px 10px 10px 10px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; 
  
}
#iconhelp_arbeitsauftrag{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right:10px;
    
}
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
#icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>




<button id="dialog-arbeitsauftrag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
      Arbeitsauftrag
     </button>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag" title="Arbeitsauftrag">
     <p> 

     Blablabla.

     </p>
</div>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" class="dialog-title-bar" title="Hilfebox">
<font face="arial" size="2">
  Some more blablabla.
</font>
</div>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '400',
   height: '200',
   dialogClass: 'hilfe_arbeitsauftrag',
   buttons: [
    {
     text: "close",
     click: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
    },
    
   ]
  });

 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });


 
 $( "#dialog-arbeitsauftrag, #icons li" ).hover(
  function() {
   $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  },
  function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  }
 );

$(".hilfe_arbeitsauftrag").children(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<span id='iconhelp' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help'></span>");

$("#iconhelp").click(function( event ){
$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog( "open" );
  event.preventDefault();
 });

$( "#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" ).dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: '200',
   height: '100',
         });
```

```css
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag {
  padding:  15.5px 0px 23px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  
 }
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }


.dialog-title-bar{
 background-color: red;
 
 
}
#dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe{
     padding:  10px 10px 10px 10px; !important
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; 
  
}
#iconhelp_arbeitsauftrag{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right:10px;
    
}
#dialog-arbeitsauftrag span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
#icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
    .ui-dialog-titlebar{
      background: red !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>




<button id="dialog-arbeitsauftrag" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
      Arbeitsauftrag
     </button>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag" title="Arbeitsauftrag">
     <p> 

     Blablabla.

     </p>
</div>



<div id="dialog_arbeitsauftrag_hilfe" class="dialog-title-bar" title="Hilfebox">
<font face="arial" size="2">
  Some more blablabla.
</font>
</div>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```